# when i click login button it shows error on con.open()

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
Public Class frmLogin
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=True;database=F:\a\Super Market Management System\Super Market Management System\db_SuperMarket.mdf")

    Private Sub frmLogin_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load



    End Sub

    Private Sub btnReset_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
        txtUsername.Clear()
        txtPassword.Clear()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClose_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click


        Dim a, b As String
        a = txtUsername.Text
        b = txtPassword.Text
        Dim flag As Integer = 0
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Login", con)
        Dim rd As SqlDataReader
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While (rd.Read())
            If (a = rd(0).ToString.Trim() And b = rd(1).ToString.Trim()) Then
                flag = 1
                Exit While
            Else
                flag = 0
            End If
        End While

        If (flag = 1) Then
            'MsgBox("Login Successfull", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Done")
            Me.Hide()


            Form1.Show()


        Else
            MsgBox("User Name or Password may be wrong.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        End If
        con.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtPassword_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtPassword.KeyDown

        If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter) Then

            btnLogin_Click(sender, e)


        End If



    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the path of database. After F: drive it should be double slash. Also add a try catch to see what exact error are you getting. You should had checked in SO for connection error questions, there must be plenty of help already

Answer (score 0):

> 1.using server explorer connect database and test it..
>
> 2.If success(test connection succeeded),copy that connection string and paste it in you code..
>
> 3.The thing is your connection string is have some problem.
>
> 4.If it dint work the pate the error and stack trace here..

Detailed Steps..

To connect to a database from Server Explorer

> From the View menu, choose Server Explorer.
>
> In Server Explorer right-click Data Connections and choose Add Connection.
>
> If this is the first connection you make, the Choose Data Source dialog box appears. Under Data Source choose the kind of data source to which you are connecting, and then under Data Provider choose the appropriate provider for the application you are working with. Finally click Continue.
>
> In the Add Connection dialog box, enter the requested information.
>
> Choose the Advanced button to open a list of settings you can change for the selected provider.
>
> Choose Test Connection to check the connection without closing the dialog box. This way you can make adjustments to the settings if the connection does not succeed.
>   Click OK.
>
> Your connection appears in Server Explorer under the Data Connections node.
>
> Copy and paste it in your code..